# simple shared pointer implementation in single threaded environment

Tags: c++, memory-management

**Update: The code below has some obvious problems, and it is not allowed to revise code in the original question, so I have to post a new question, [the revised code is here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231732/simple-shared-pointer-implementation-in-single-threaded-environment-revised).**

`std::shared_ptr` has the potential problem that two pointer point to the same object but to different control blocks. And its atomic operation is pure overhead in a single threaded environment. So I wrote the following version to avoid these problems. This implementation also has the advantage that an empty pointer is the same size as a `void *`.

```
template <typename T>
struct ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr {

private:
    struct Pair {
        T data;
        size_t cnt;
        template <typename ... Args>
        Pair(Args && ... args): data(std::forward<Args>(args)...), cnt(1) {}
    };
    Pair *ptr;

public:
    template <typename ... Args>
    static ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr make(Args && ... args) {
        ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr p;
        p.ptr = new Pair(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return p;
    }

    ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr() : ptr(nullptr) {}

    ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr(const ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr & other) : ptr(other.ptr) {
        if (ptr && &other != this) {
            ++(ptr->cnt);
        }
    }
    ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr & operator=(const ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr & other) {
        ptr = other.ptr;
        if (ptr && &other != this) {
            ++(ptr->cnt);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr(ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr && other) : ptr(other.ptr) {
        if (&other != this) {
            other.ptr = nullptr;
        }
    }
    ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr & operator=(ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr && other) {
        if (&other != this) {
            ptr = other.ptr;
            other.ptr = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~ThreadUnsafeSharedPtr() {
        if (ptr) {
            if(--ptr->cnt == 0) {
                delete ptr;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have reverted the changes which invalidates the answer. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation misses to implement pointer semantics in the form of an overloaded `operator->()` and `operator*()`.

Isn't that the whole point of a *pointer* surrogate?